# getCreate2Address (create2) UNABLE to get correct contract address :(

Tags: create2, etherjs

UPDATE: I think the real question is what to use as Init code? The contract has no constructor. Can someone help on this?

Basically i am using openzeppelin Clones.sol contract to determine the deployed contract address(using implementation and the contract address that launches the contract)
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol

I want to do the same thing on the client-side using etherJS. Apparently getCreate2Address does the same thing in js as create2 does in solidity.
HOWEVER i am unable to get it to work.
I verified that the salt generated is CORRECT(same as in contract), but i get different address from the one in the smart contract.

For init code, i copied the input created during the generation of the implementation contract(the one we are copying).
For fromAddress i use the contract that launches the proxy contract.

The generated contractAddress in etherjs DOES NOT match the one in solidity :(
What could i possibly be doing wrong? I am getting desperate at this point and have no clue how to resolve the issue.

Apparently the "initCode" should be the bytecode + concatenated constructor arguments (My contract has no arguments, so i just use the bytecode as initCode. Is this correct?

Am i inputting wrong init code? Because i don't know where else the problem could be. The salt generated in etherjs matches the solidity one, but the contract generated does not. Big F.

[image: init code]

```
let userWallet = "myWallet" //user wallet address
let specificId = 0
let fromAddress = "contract that launches the proxy" //MAIN CONTRACT
let salt = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["bytes", "uint256", "address"], [ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(ethers.utils.hexlify(1), 1), specificId, userWallet])
let initCode = "initCodeHere"
let initCodeHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(initCode); //initcode should be bytecode
let contractAddress = ethers.utils.getCreate2Address(fromAddress, salt, initCodeHash);

console.log("SALT WORKS" + salt)
console.log(contractAddress)
```